# Is there a way to capture the event fired by onUserInteraction()

Tags: android

I'm using [onUserInteraction()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserInteraction()) but I need to disregard key presses from the Bluetooth keyboard attached to the device. I can't seem to locate where the event that's triggering the callback is kept so I can't examine what the nature of the Interaction was.

Is there no way to capture it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onUserInteraction()` is called from [dispatchKeyEvent()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#3271) which has `KeyEvent` as parameter and is public so you can override it

```
override fun dispatchKeyEvent(event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
    if (event.source == InputDeviceCompat.SOURCE_KEYBOARD) {
        // Do something
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event)
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what syntax you're using there, but I've translated it into Java and it works perfectly. Thanks very much.

Comment: @GeniaS. It's written in Kotlin.